# How to recreate Figma's Smart Animate effect in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to "smart animate" transitions between screens with similar layouts in `jetpack compose`?

That is, if I'm using 2 different sized app bars is there a way to animate the transition rather than having it pop back and forth between both sizes.  I read somewhere that compose can animate screen transitions, but I'm not sure if its the same thing I'm trying to do.

Basically, I'm want to recreate the way Figma's "smart animate" transition blends between objects on screen transitions, so the appbars grow or shrink.  From what I remember reading about screen transitions, it sounded like it was for slide in/out for the entire screen.
Is there a simple way to do this or would I have to manually setup the animation using `Compose Animation`?